# Can a new company make a processor compatible with Windows and current software?

Tags: computer-architecture

Would anyone apart from Intel and AMD ever be able to make a processor that can be used on a personal computer, or is it impossible? I believe it is due to them owning the x86 instruction set, which means that a company doesn't have the right to produce a processor which could run a personal computer. But what if the processor used a different instruction set, but in between it translated the x86 architecture to its own? Would that also be breaching the ownership?

Comment: I don't follow why you assume personal computers must use an x86 architecture. Raspberry Pi is built around a Broadcom processor - does that meet your definition of a personal computer ?

Comment: @gandalf61 Well I meant a computer which is useful for everything a personal user might want like all the variety of software and games that are out there. I don't see any other processors than the ones produced by Intel and AMD that actually have the potential to do that. And they are both x86, I thought it was something to do with that? I gave my best guess why it is like that, but I am waiting for answers.

Comment: While I think this is widely offtopic here, a few quick comments. 1) Modern CPUs do not actually run x86; it's so horrible an instruction set that they have dedicated chips that translate it into something usable. 2) The OS doesn't intercept instructions between application memory and CPU. As long as your program is written in (read: compile to) the correct binary format, the CPU can execute it. 3) That said, the OS itself must be available in the format, of course! Which _would_ represent a major hurdle for a new architecture; you'd at least want to provide a cross-compiler.

Comment: And, of course, your new CPU could just accept x86 as input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory a new microprocessor manufacturer could enter the market. In practice this is very unlikely, but not for any reason to do with the x86 architecture - the barrier is economics.

Manufacturing modern microprocessors is a highly complex engineering challenge which requires a lot of very expensive equipment. Getting the design right in the first place requires a massive upfront investment. And the profit margin on each unit is tiny, so in order to turn a profit you also have the additional overhead of investing in automation - you cannot just employ an army of production line staff.

A saturated market place with established players, high fixed costs and low profit margins is not going to be attractive to start-ups or new entrants, or to their investors.

The one thing that might change this is a breakthrough in technology. If you invent a way to manufacture a portable quantum computer from household waste in your garage using a few DIY tools, then you are home and dry.

Comment: While what you write isn't untrue, it's certainly not the full truth. ARM, for instance, has come up rather strongly. Multiple "niche" architectures exist happily, too, for specialized use cases. In the end, it's about tooling.